# how to read a row from a text file, save it to variable and then use it in a bash command

Tags: bash

I have a list.txt file containing a single column of 3 values (1 , 0 , 0) , I want read the values from each row into a variable and then  use it in a command

I tried to do this:

```
for i in {1..3}
do
a=`sed -n "$i"p list.txt`

b="fslmaths HCP"$i".nii.gz -mul "$a" posMEM/HCP"$i".nii.gz"
echo $b
done
```

but I got the following output instead:

```
 posMEM/HCP1.nii.gzz -mul 1
 posMEM/HCP2.nii.gzz -mul 0
 posMEM/HCP3.nii.gzz -mul 0
```

what I was hoping to get is

```
fslmaths HCP1.nii.gz -mul 1 posMEM/HCP1.nii.gz
fslmaths HCP2.nii.gz -mul 0 posMEM/HCP2.nii.gz
fslmaths HCP3.nii.gz -mul 0 posMEM/HCP3.nii.gz
```

Comment: the given code is working for me!!!, for betterment, please provide the full path of `list.txt` in the script.

Comment: oh that's strange, i tried putting in the full path, it did not make any difference

Comment: can you try to run the script in debug mode: `bash -x yourscript.sh` and see what's happening...

Comment: `list.txt` may contain dos `\r` character.

Comment: I simply copied and pasted a column from excel file into list.txt. If so, how do I remove that \r

Comment: I got the error `script.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'cript.sh: line 2: `do` when I did bash -x script.sh

Comment: @JunhongYu: Perform:  `dos2unix list.txt` and try executing again the script. As mentioned by @tshiono, it could be due to Windows carriage returns that the txt file is behaving differently.